# PHP- Join Multiple Tables not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have two tables in my database.

I want to compare the ***each row*** of `Email` of `table-1` with the ***each row*** of `Email2` of `table-2` if their content matches then I want to store the `Mac` of `table-2` to `Mac` of `Result table` .

#### this is table-1

```
Name       Email

name1      user1@xy.com
name2      user2@xy.com
```

#### this is table-2

```
Email2           Mac

user1@xy.com     77777
abc@xy.com       88888
```

#### this is Result Table

```
ID      Mac

1     77777
2     xxxxx
```

Currently I am using this code to compare and insert data in result_table . It is not running as expected. **Its not even comparing Email1 and Email2 instead of, it just keeps on dumping the the values(Mac) multiple times in table like 28 times  on running script only one single time.**

```
<?php
include 'conn.php';
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into result_tbale(mac)
select table2.mac from table2
inner join table1 on table1.email = table1.email");

?>
```

*I am well aware the similar questions is being asked before but none of them is like my question or has complete a answer that's why I asked*

Comment: @jarlh edited it was mistaken

Comment: insert into result_table (mac) values (
select table2.mac from table2
inner join table1 on table1.email = table2.email)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have typo in the join condition:

...inner join table1 on table1.email = table**2**.email**2**

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug in your code. You are using `table1` twice in the `ON` clause of your query:

```
insert into result_table (mac)
select table2.mac from table2
inner join table1 on table1.email = table2.email
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/27978/1)

Comment: tried this, now its not inserting anything. Also no errors

Comment: No, `VALUES` is not used in the context of an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` query. Try executing just the select statement. Does it return anything?

Comment: I assume this` insert into result_table (mac) values (
select table2.mac from table2
inner join table1 on table1.email = table2.email)`   but not confirm sir.

Comment: @devpro No, the statement is OK as it is. I'll setup an sqlfiddle demo.

Comment: Than maybe selection is not working or maybe this `table1.email = table2.email2`

Answer (score 0):

Your inner join seems useless because you join on `table1.email=table1.email.`

You need to join on `table2.email`

Comment: could you add this after your mysqli_query("...") or die(mysqli_error());

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that your join looks to be on the same field.  Try changing your join such that `table1.email = table2.email`

Answer (score 0):

Your inner join is wrong, and if what your columns are called is correct than you should have the following:

```
table1.email = table2.email2
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want

```
insert into results (mac)
    select t2.mac
    from table1 t1
    join table2 t2
        on t1.email = t2.email;
```

The SQL Fiddle for it:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5d311/1